# Lubuntu 12.04 won't boot after install

Tags: 12.04, boot, lubuntu

I just installed Lubuntu 12.04 on my laptop (Compaq Presario V5000). It seemed to install fine, but after the install completed it stops booting when it gets to the Blue Lubuntu screen.

I have the CD removed and the ethernet cable unplugged. Any help would be great!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu 12.04 has not been supported for 6 months.  It reached End Of Life in October of last year.  I am not sure if that has anything to do with your problem but I would recommend that you download and install Lubuntu 14.04 which is the newest version.